# How do I integrate a third-party library into october cms?

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I need to add the payment system library to my project on Ocrober CMS ( https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-checkout-sdk-php ). In this regard, the question is:

Can I do this using only the classes of my plugin, or is there a way to automatically integrate this into the project? If so, how can I do this without rewriting namespace and use at the beginning of php files? There is information about this on Github, but it is not clear how to use it.

Comment: you can use composer, init with composer in your plugins root directory and add this lib using `composer require` , it will available automatically in you component / or project wide.

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I installed composer in my openserver, how do I add this class (or plugin) to my OctoberCMS build now? 
P.S. I have never Worked with composer, especially in conjunction with October.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install `composer` in your `system/server`
2. `open terminal` and `go to in your plugin's root folder` for ex. `plugins/author/pluginName`
3. `composer require stripe/stripe-php` <- use this command `please replace package as per your need`
4. once package installation is done you are able to use your library, for ex: `$stripeClient = new \Stripe\StripeClient()...`

### according to your need

1. `in terminal` go to your `plugin's root directory`
2. `composer init` -> then fill default infos
3. `composer require yandex-money/yandex-checkout-sdk-php`
4. use it in code

```
// import 
use YandexCheckout\Client;

// use
$client = new Client();
$client->setAuth('shopId', 'secretKey');
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything seems to work. In the future, I will read the documentation, because the tool is useful and very popular. I'm already ashamed not to know((

Comment: I am glad it helped you, yes composer is great tool :), its never late to learn new things , now you know composer  cheers .